# setCellValue is deprecated

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In my project, I am adding the functionality of generating Excel file using Apache Poi library in a Spring project, using the below code.

```
public class ExcelView extends AbstractExcelView {
     @Override
     protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
       HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws Exception {

      List<Employee> employees = (List) model.get("employees");
      HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Report");

      HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
      header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Employee Id");
      header.createCell(1).setCellValue("First Name");
      header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Last Name");
      header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Salary");

      int counter = 1;
      for (Employee e : employees) {
       HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(counter++);
       row.createCell(0).setCellValue(e.getEmployeeId());
       row.createCell(1).setCellValue(e.getFirstName());
       row.createCell(2).setCellValue(e.getLastName());
       row.createCell(3).setCellValue(e.getSalary());
      }
     }
}
```

My problem is `row.createCell(0).setCellValue();` is deprecated. What is replacement for this method?

Comment: i think you are calling `createCell(short columnIndex)` which is deprecated instead of this you need to call `createCell(int column)`.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to the latest version of Apache POI, currently 3.12?

Comment: @Prashant  Your solution worked for me,  just changed  createCell(short columnIndex) to createCell(int column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("your string"));` instead

or upgrade your poi.jar to the latest version.

Comment: thanks,@Howard,It removes my warning message.I used the latest poi-3.4 final jar

Comment: I think the POI javadoc and code are not sync. The official javadoc does not deprecate setCellValue(String)

Comment: The POI javadocs on the website always refer to the latest version. For historic javadocs, you need to use the javadocs bundled with the download for the version you're using